# Bind Two Values Into Model for select box

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I currently have a select box which holds a list of users obtained from a backend. At the moment, this select box is binded to the name property of my ng model.

However, the user object also holds an email property and I would like to bind this property to an email property in the model as well as the name property when a user selects a name from the dropdown menu.

Can this be done?

Below is my current select box which works fine to bind to the name property in my ng model:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model.name" name ='name'>
    <option value="">--Select a User--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user.name">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understood that correctly: you want 2 different select, one for users and one for emails? They must be connected? I mean, when you choose user = "John" the second select should be automatically be "john@xxx.com"?

Comment: @alesssz Basically I want one select box to update the 2 properties on ngModel: name and email when a user selects a name from the one select box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by obtaining the index when looping through my users array for select options and using this index as the value. Then I added a change property on the select tag which then uses this index to obtain the information from my users array and set it correctly to the model:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser" name ='name' (change)="userChange()">
    <option value="" selected="true">--Select a User--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let user of users; let i=index" [value]="i">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Then in my component:

```
userChange() {
    this.model.name = this.users[this.selectedUser].name;
    this.model.email = this.users[this.selectedUser].email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model" name ='name'>
    <option value="">--Select a User--</option>
    <option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user">{{user.name}}</option>
</select>
```

If you select the whole object you should be able to select the email and the name of the user.

Comment: Then wouldn't the name property contain the full user object meaning I would have to fire an event when the value changes to update the name and email properties to their correct values?

Comment: If the model type is qual to the user type it should update the model by default. If not you can fire an event and update those values.

Comment: Thanks, however when trying to bind to an object, the model keeps expecting a string, therefore I get "[object Object]" returned. I've tried setting a property in the model called user to hold the user object with a type of object and then with a type of any but it always comes back as the object string